# How to sort by date in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net, .net, blazor

I'm a beginner in .NET, and I need to sort my ToDo List by date. I have this code, but it doesn't sort. I want to make sorting by button.

I think the `@foreach` is the problem, but I already tried to rewrite it in some others options. I searched every site on google, but every time it was too different to use it in my code.

```
@page "/todo"
@using System.Linq

<PageTitle>Todo</PageTitle>

<h2>Progress bar</h2>
<label for="file">Progress:</label>
<progress id="file" value=@PocetSplnenych max=@CelkovyPocet></progress>

<h1>Todo (@todos.Count(todo => !todo.IsDone))</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var todo in todos)
    {
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" @bind="todo.IsDone" />
            <input @bind="todo.Title" />
            <input @bind="todo.date" />
            <input @bind="todo.Priority" />
         
            
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<h3>Hotové (@todos2.Count(todo => !todo.IsDone))</h3>

<ul>
    @foreach (var todo in todos2)
    {
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" @bind="todo.IsDone" />
            <input @bind="todo.Title" />
            <input @bind="todo.date" />
            <input @bind="todo.Priority" />
            
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<input placeholder="Úkol" @bind="newTodo" />
<input type="date" placeholder="Select a date" @bind="date" />
<input placeholder="Jaká je priorita?" @bind="newPriority" />
<button @onclick="AddTodo">přidat</button>
<button @onclick="Delete">smazat</button>
<button @onclick="Move">přesunout</button>
<button @onclick="Sort">Seřadit</button>

@code {
    private List<TodoItem> todos = new();
    private string? newTodo;
    private DateOnly date;
    private string? newPriority;

    private void Sort()
    {
        foreach (var received in todos.OrderBy(a => a.date)) 
        {
            @received.date
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `TodoItem` class look like? What's the datatype of your `date` column?

Answer (score 3):

You can use directly the order by linq extension method inside your foreach:

```html
<ul>
    @foreach (var todo in todos.OrderBy(t => t.date))
    {
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" @bind="todo.IsDone" />
            <input @bind="todo.Title" />
            <input @bind="todo.date" />
            <input @bind="todo.Priority" />
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```